# Playground execution aborted - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsstring

I have just started IOS development and i was trying to do some manipulations with the strings

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let newTypeString = NSString(string: str) // here is the error
//this is NSString that i used to create newTypeString NSString(string: String)
```

And this is the error I have encountered:

> Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted,
>   reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Did anyone else encounter this error?

Comment: That code runs without problems in a Playground. Please update the question  with your real problem, otherwise both question and answer are useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```
NSString(string: String)
```

You are trying to create an `NSString` instance using a `String` variable named `String`. But `String`, is a type, not a variable. So your previous line works because you are passing it a variable:

```
let newTypeString = NSString(string: str)
```

But the one where you don't pass an actual variable, but instead pass in a type, fails. Does that make sense?

**Update:**
It appears that I misunderstood the code as it was originally formatted. The only code the OP was trying to run was:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let newTypeString = NSString(string: str)
```

According to the provided information, Playgrounds would crash on the second line even though the code was correct. I suggested that the OP try relaunching Xcode to see if that would resolve the issue since Xcode can sometimes be a bit temperamental :) Apparently, that solved the issue.

Comment: The line `let newTypeString = NSString(string: str)` executes fine and I see no issues with it. So, not sure why it should crash for you. Perhaps you might want to try restarting Xcode to see if this is some sort of Xcode issues at your end?

Comment: @Fahim This is totally unrelated to `Xcode`, this has to do with the other code he's got. Might be helpful to post the full crash log...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Since he says that the crash occurs on a given line and he's only provided two lines, I am not sure what else to think. Unless he's got more code in the playground. Which he has not stated is the case, though I guess it could be.

Comment: @DionizB Happy to help :)

Comment: `NSString(string: String)` would cause a compiler error  and not a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. So it is unclear to me how this answers the question.

Comment: @MartinR You are right - it would have been a compiler error if it was that line but I thought Xcode was being temperamental, as it is sometimes prone to. However, I apparently misunderstood the code as it was originally formatted. The issue did turn out to be an Xcode issue and since I mentioned that in the comments, I believe the OP marked it as the correct response. I will update the answer to clarify.